# Inheritence paint clipping

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, paint, jcomponent

I am trying to create an object that looks like this-
http://www.cs.uwlax.edu/~riley/CS120S13/Assignments/Assignment11.pdf

The face at the top of the page is my desired result.

What I did was I was given a class called BouncyFace that would draw the body of the face and my job is to inherit the paint method from BouncyFace and alter it so that it adds the eyes and mouth to the face. I have added the eyes, but the mouth is a little tricky because it is an oval on top of another oval and I cant simply change the color of one oval in the paint method as it will change the color of all the ovals. Thoughts?

For those who want the code: Here is the code of BouncyFace

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class BouncyFace extends JComponent  {
    protected int xDelta = 1;
    protected int yDelta = 1;
    protected Color fleshColor;
    public BouncyFace(int x, int y, int side)  {
        super();
        setBounds(x, y, side, side);
        fleshColor = new Color(214,157,106);
        setBackground(fleshColor);
        setForeground(Color.black);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
   }
```

And the code for the class that is inheriting BouncyFace:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Features extends BouncyFace
{
    public Features(int x,int y, int side)
    {
        super(x,y,side);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor( Color.black);
        g.fillOval(10,20,10,10);
        g.fillOval(40,20,10,10);
        //super.fillOval(10,10,40,35);
        g.fillOval(10,10,40,40);
    }
}
```

This post is basically asking how to use different colored ovals in the same method in the paint method.

Comment: Yes, you can. Save the current color. Change it. Do your painting. Restore the old color.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getColor()

Comment: Edit: Ok, So Esentially Im adding a color paramater?

Comment: `I was given a class called BouncyFace that would draw the body of the face and my job is to inherit the paint method from BouncyFace and alter it so that it adds the eyes and mouth to the face` - I would get a new teacher because custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method. Tell your teacher this, because we are tired of repeating this advice multiple times every day because a teacher can't teach painting properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to save and restore a color you would do something like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Color c = g.getColor();
    g.setColor( Color.black);
    g.fillOval(10,20,10,10);
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillOval(40,20,10,10);
    //super.fillOval(10,10,40,35);
    g.fillOval(10,10,40,40);
}
```

Comment: However, that changes the color of all the ovals. I only want it to change the color of one oval.

Comment: I saved the color before it was changed to black and restored it back after one oval was drawn.  I assumed it was something different in the beginning. Wasn't it?

Comment: Oh! It worked, I wasnt putting the ovals in the write order :/. Thank you wise sir.

Comment: ok I have One last Question, I will create another child class of BouncyFace and its task is to alter paint in a way so that it colors one of the small ovals red, how can I accomplish this

Comment: Exactly the same way. What's the difference?

Comment: hmm ok so if i set c as something in a new paint it will still use it in the old paint?

Comment: `c` is just a `local` variable. It goes out of scope as soon as the method finishes.